# Resharper nightly builds license

Tags: resharper

Are Resharper nightly builds free for use in a commercial project?
I cannot find this information on jetbrans' site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every nightly build contains a trial license that usually expires in 30 days. It also contains a time bomb that triggers in ~45 days after publishing.

Other than these time limits, there's nothing that prevents you from using nightly builds in production.

Permanent licenses from previous
   versions may or may not work with
   nightly builds:

- If your license
  makes you eligible for the same major
  version (4.x, 5.x etc.) that the
  current nightly builds belong to (for
  example, we've made available early
  access programs for 5.1, 5.1.1, and
  5.1.2), your license key will work with nightly builds.
- If you own a
  5.x license purchased April 25, 2011 or earlier, it won't work with 6.x
  nightly builds, in which case you'll
  still be able to use a 30-day free
  evaluation period with each 6.x
  nightly build.
- If you own a 5.x
  license purchased on April 26, 2011
  or later, your license key should
  work with 6.x.

Answer (score 1):

No, the nightly builds are just trial versions unless you have a valid product key. If you have a 5.X product key, it will work with the 6.0 nightly builds.

Comment: Not exactly: in general, 5.x licenses shouldn't work with 6.x nightly builds